# Data from a controller is not showing using ng-repeat and factory

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get data to be displayed in a table using ng-repeat.

I have a factory coded like this:

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />

var studentService = angular.module('StudentService', []);

studentService.factory('studentApi', function ($http) {
    var urlBase = "http://localhost:60892/api";

    var student = {};

    student.getStudents = function() {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/Students');
    }

    return student;
})
```

and my main module is coded like so

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />

var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'StudentService']);

//app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
//    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
//}]);

app.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/Add', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/add.html',
                controller: 'AddController'
            })
            .when('/Edit', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html',
                controller: 'EditController'
            })
            .when('/Delete', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/delete.html',
                controller: 'DeleteController'
            })
            .when('/Home', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/Home'
            });
    }
]);

app.controller('AddController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "In add view"
});

app.controller('DeleteController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "In delete view"
});

app.controller('EditController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "In edit view"
});

app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, studentApi) {
    getStudents();
    function getStudents() {
        studentApi.getStudents().then(function (students) {
                debugger;
            $scope.students = students;
        },
        function(error) {
            $scope.status = "Unable to retrieve data from the database: " + error.message;
        })

    }
});
```

In inspecting, I can see that a I get a response from my web api.

```
Array(27)
0
:
{Id: 1, FirstName: "Daryl", LastName: "Richards", Age: 32, Gender: "Female"}
1
:
{Id: 2, FirstName: "Fuller", LastName: "Guzman", Age: 27, Gender: "Male"}
2
:
{Id: 3, FirstName: "Levi", LastName: "Lamb", Age: 32, Gender: "Male"}
3
:
{Id: 4, FirstName: "Jared", LastName: "Bradley", Age: 32, Gender: "Female"}
.
.
.
length
:
27
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

But when I try to print it in my html table, the table creates 6 rows but it doesn't have any values in it. Even when I use inspect element to see the `<td>` values, there is none. Below is my html code.

```
<div class="row" >
    <h1 class="text-center text-primary">Students</h1>
    <hr/>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type to filter records" class="input-lg form-control ng-model="txtFilter"/>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student Id</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="s in students track by $index">
                        <td>{{s.Id}}</td>
                        <td>{{s.FirstName}}</td>
                        <td>{{s.LastName}}</td>
                        <td>{{s.Age}}</td>
                        <td>{{s.Gender}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you need this $scope.students = students.data; instead of $scope.students = students; when you calling your service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `response` object got from web service to `$scope.students`. Due to this view is not getting updated. The `response` object is not an array, so it will not iterate. The response object contains `data` field which will hold the data came from the server. So you need to assign data field from response object.

Just do one change in your `getStudents()` method from controller,

```
$scope.students = students;
```

to

```
$scope.students = students.data;
```

Comment: @stackquestions pleasure to help.